# Write todays date into registry from .reg file

Tags: windows-7, registry

I need to write the current date using a .reg file into the registry in Windows 7.

I have a .bat file that works properly with

```
WshShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings\abc.accdr\Param\FRD", Date(), "REG_SZ"
```

and want to use a .reg file with

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings\abc.accdr\Param\]
"FRD"=date()
```

where `date()` is the current date and is entered in the registry as `5/24/13`

I need to know what to use for the `date()` variable as `date()` does not work, nor `date`

Comment: You can't.  A .reg file only contains static text.  There is no way to have it do any processing.  You'll need to keep using your code (your example is VBScript not .bat BTW)

Answer (score 0):

This works from the command prompt -

echo %date%

It just accesses the environment variable for the current date and time so you should be able to set a variable equal to %date%

Comment: I'm a novice when it come to .reg files, how would I use that?

Answer (score -1):

Try this (if you want to add the key/value via command line):

```
REG ADD HKCU\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings\abc.accdr\Param /v FRD /t REG_SZ /d %date%
```